# libGDX: Share-button to share a simple String in e.g. Facebook, E-Mail, WhatsApp, Twitter

Tags: android, libgdx, share, social-networking

I have a little problem in my application, I hope somebody can help me.
I want to share a simple string from my game on e.g. social netwoks
by tapping on a button. I use libGDX with Android Studio.

Thanks for helpful answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) for your requirement

1. Create Interface in core module

   ```
   public interface Services {

      void share();
   }
   ```
2. Implement above interface to `AndroidLauncher` class and write implementation, share object of implemented class to core module and from core module call share method

   ```
   @Override
   public void share() {

       Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
       sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, R.string.app_name);

       String sAux = "\nLet me recommend you this game\n\n";
       sAux = sAux + AppInfo.PLAYSTORE_LINK+getPackageName()+" \n\n";

       sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

   }
   ```

**EDIT**

- `PLAYSTORE_LINK` is a static constant String inside my `AppInfo` class, You can keep in your own class or you can replace with String value.

  ```
  public static final String PLAYSTORE_LINK= "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=";
  ```
- You've two interface and you're using both inferface reference in Your `ApplicationListener` implemented class.

  1. Either create a parent interface of both interface and implement `AndroidLauncher` class with parent interface and catch reference in `ApplicationListener` implemented class, Downcast and call respective method.
  2. Pass two argument in Constructor and keep reference in core module, then call method.
- Keep reference

  ```
  public class GdxTest extends ApplicationAdapter{

      Service service;

    public GdxTest(Service service) {
       this.service=service;
    }
  }
  ```
- Add Listener to your object

  ```
  TextButton x= new TextButton("SHARE",skin);
  x.addListener(new ClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
          service.share();
          super.clicked(event, x, y);
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Nice, thank you. It looks almost good in my code, but
 1. How can I implement 2 interfaces, because I need 2 in my AndroidLauncher and 2. "AppInfo" gives me an error with the remark " Cannot resolve symbol 'AppInfo'.

Comment: And at least how can I call that lines of code, because I want to share the string by **tapping on a button**

Answer (score -1):

```
 btn_share.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

           Gdx.net.openURI("http://share_adress.html");

            super.clicked(event, x, y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: While this might solve the original question, it's best to include a description of your code so we know what is going on.